# Are there natural number satisfying the following equations?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logarithms, natural-numbers

The motivation comes from the following question on MathOverflow:

*[Is the exponential version of Catalan-Dickson conjecture true?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306499/is-the-exponential-version-of-catalan-dickson-conjecture-true)*

> **Question 1.** Is there a natural number $n$ satisfying the equation $n(n+1)=2^{[\log^{n}_{2}]+2}$ where $[.]$ indicates the floor function. I am also interested in the minimum $n$ satisfying this equation if there is any.

As the answer to the above question is negative, let's consider the following more generalized form:

> **Question 2.**  Are there natural number $n$ and prime number $p$ satisfying the equation $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{p}{p-1}\times p^{[\log_{p}^{n}]}+\frac{p-2}{p-1}\times p^n$ where $[.]$ indicates the floor function. (Note that for $p=2$ we get the previous equation.)

Comment: Well for $n>1$ the left hand side would not be a power of $2$, so no.

Comment: Anyway, what is $\log_2^n$?

Comment: For the more general question, $\frac{p-2}{p-1}\cdot p^n$ quickly outgrows $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RHS of $$n(n+1)=2^{[\log^{n}_{2}]+2}$$ is a power of $2$ while the LHS is not a power of $2$ unless $n=1$ and $n=1$ is not a solution.

Thus I would say there are no solutions for this equation.

Comment: And for the second question the left side is an integer while the right side is probably not.   It is difficult to get rid of the $p-1$ in the denominator.